# Display textView on ImageView programatically in RelativeLayout in HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, layoutparams

I want to display images and text on each image in a horizontalScrollView.
for this I am using RelativeLayout inside horizontalScrollView and adding ImageView and TextView dynamically. It appears as below. the image is displayed only of the text length.
text1 text2 text3 text4 text5 text6  |
  |    |    |    |    |    |         |
i1| i2 | i3 | i4 | i5 | i6 |    i7   |
  |    |    |    |    |    |         |
Below is my code.

```
         for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++){                       
                         imageView = new ImageView (con);
                         textView=new TextView(con);                          
                         imageView.setId(50+j);
                         textView.setId(50+j);

                        //set image to imageView
                         new vdoImageLoader(videos.get(j),imageView,con).execute(null, null);

                     if (j == 0) {
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                                      RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                       RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                              rlp1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
                               rlp1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);

                               imageView.setLayoutParams(rlp1);
                             vdoRelativeLayout.addView(imageView);

                           RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                                   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);   

                          rlp2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM, imageView.getId());   

                           textView.setLayoutParams(rlp2);
                           vdoRelativeLayout.addView(textView);                         

                       } else {

                           RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                                  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                           rlp2.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, imageView.getId() - 1);

                           imageView.setLayoutParams(rlp2);
                             vdoRelativeLayout.addView(imageView);

                         RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                                   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);   

                         rlp1.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, imageView.getId()-1); 
                         rlp1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM, imageView.getId()-1); 

                           textView.setLayoutParams(rlp1);
                           vdoRelativeLayout.addView(textView);     
                       }                                                  
                     }
```

Comment: no by mistake it got reversed.

Comment: You should be able to ... reverse the reversion ... by viewing the edits. There should be a "rollback" button.